# Mock function not found in EasyMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, easymock

I am trying to build my first EasyMock test, however I have a trivial problem that the function "mock" is not found.

Here is my pretty straightforward code:

```java
package homework;

import org.easymock.EasyMockSupport;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.locusenergy.homework.Elevator;

public class ElevatorTest extends EasyMockSupport{

    private Elevator elevator;

    @Before 
      public void setUp() {
        elevator = mock(Elevator.class);

      } 

    @Test
    public void testCallElevator() {
        elevator.requestFloor(5);
    }
}
```

However, I am getting an error that mock is not found. I have no idea how to fix this issue.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on Documentationof EasyMock the example should look like this:

```java
package homework;

import org.easymock.EasyMockSupport;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.locusenergy.homework.Elevator;

public class ElevatorTest extends EasyMockSupport{

    private Elevator elevator;

    @Before 
      public void setUp() {
        elevator = createMock(Elevator.class);
      } 

    @Test
    public void testCallElevator() {
        elevator.requestFloor(5);
    }
}
```

As described here: http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/EasyMockSupport.html

The API Docs say the methods nameis createMock thats all.

Comment: Thank you, I was following [this](http://easymock.org/user-guide.html#mocking) and they were using function mock(). Do you know what I can use instead of partialMockBuilder? Could you tell me why there is a difference in the method naming?

Comment: Sorry never used easyMock ;) Only googled the Classname checked the API Docs :D I would advice you to studie the get starting guide at easymock homepage. And the linked docs. Keep an eye on the version you are using, to read the right docs!

Answer (score 1):

Your code probably will work as it is when the next version of EasyMock is released.

The user guide refers to the `mock` method which can be found in the [master branch](https://github.com/easymock/easymock/blob/master/easymock/src/main/java/org/easymock/EasyMockSupport.java#L66) but is not in the latest release (3.3.1).

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing another approach...
You can use org.easymock.IMocksControl.
Your code will look something like below 
....

```
@Before 
  public void setUp() {
   IMocksControl mocksControl = createControl();
   elevator = = mocksControl.createMock(Elevator.class); 
 }
```

.....
I prefer using IMocksControl. As the name\api suggest  controls the behavior of its associated mock object.

Note : I am using easymock version 3.1
Regards,
MB